# Entity Framework Core Get All Inserted Entity Ids

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am running a loop of inserts like so (sort of pseudo code):

```
             var IdLinks= new List<link>();
                foreach (var item in List)
                {
                    var entity= new MyEntity();
                    entity.col1= item.x;
                    entity.col2= item.y;                  

                    _db.MyEntity.Add(entity);

                    var insertedId= _db.Entry(entity).Property(e => e.ID).CurrentValue;
                    Ids.Add(new Link{Id1=item.id, Id2 =insertedId});
                }
                _db.SaveChanges();
```

I want to be able to create a list that contains links between the list I am looping and the inserted IDs of the items I am creating.

Previously as part of a transaction the line

```
var id= _db.Entry(entity).Property(e => e.ID).CurrentValue;
```

updated to the correct Id when I was adding relational data in a transaction but in this instance the temporary Id remains (eg -23234232).

How can I get all the "real" Ids for each inserted row that has been added so I can add them to my list?

Comment: If the values are generated in the database, then you can get them after executing the SaveChanges method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, the IDs are only generated once the SaveChanges() is called. Fortunately, EF will populate the IDs in the entity object references when they are inserted, so the solution is to keep the entity references and get the IDs after saving.

If you are recording the original list item's ID as part of the new entity this is quite simple:

```
List<MyEntity> insertedEntities = new List<MyEntity>();

foreach (var item in List)
{
    var entity= new MyEntity();
    entity.col1= item.x;
    entity.col2= item.y;                  
    entity.originalId = item.id;

    _db.MyEntity.Add(entity);
    insertedEntities.Add(entity);
}
_db.SaveChanges();
var Ids = insertedEntities
    .Select(x => new link { id1 = x.originalId, id2 = x.id })
    .ToList();
```

If you aren't recording the original list item ID as part of the new entity then it gets a tad trickier. We can use a Dictionary to associate the original ID to the new entity:

```
Dictionary<int,MyEntity> insertedEntities = new Dictionary<int,MyEntity>();

foreach (var item in List)
{
    var entity= new MyEntity();
    entity.col1= item.x;
    entity.col2= item.y;                  

    _db.MyEntity.Add(entity);
    insertedEntities.Add(item.id, entity);
}
_db.SaveChanges();
var Ids = insertedEntities
    .Select(x => new link { id1 = x.Key, id2 = x.Value.id })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. It was the storing of the entire entity I needed.